# Setting up alarms for Cloudwatch Insight Queries

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm looking to setup alarms based on thresholds of particular log events, such as "failed logins".  I have an Insight query that returns all my log entries I'm interested in.  Is there a way I can setup metrics and alarms based on Insight queries? I found an editor to do this in Metrics but unable to save it, and can't select my log groups. I feel like I'm missing something. Thanks!

My example Insights query here:

fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message LIKE "User login failed"
| parse @message "* * [*] *" as date, level, object, message
| sort @timestamp desc

I tried adding this query to the editor in Metrics but it won't save.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a metric filter for your log group and then configure an alarm based on the metric filter -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create_alarm_log_group_metric_filter.html

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much. That was pretty easy to do based on the instructions given above. I was approaching this from a different way, but easy to setup the Metric (keywords in the logs) and then alarms.  Thanks Kavish!